# Write on thermal printer device in golang

Tags: linux, go, thermal-printer

I have a thermal printer(ESC/POS) already configured on my linux machine and using the terminal command (as root) I can make it print:

```
echo "Hello!" > /dev/usb/lp0
```

However, doing the same procedure in golang nothing happens:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
   fmt.Println("Hello Would!")

   f, err := os.Open("/dev/usb/lp0")

   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }

   defer f.Close()

   f.Write([]byte("Hello world!"))
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe something like https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gousb?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As described in the documentation [`os.Open()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) opens a file read-only.

You would have discovered the problem if you had checked the return from your [`Write()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write) call. Always check errors. Don't ignore them, even in tiny programs like this; they will give you a clue as to what is wrong.

To fix the problem, open the device special for writing with [`os.OpenFile()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile).

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("/dev/usb/lp0", os.O_RDWR, 0)
```